# how to find which script in a webpage actually overwrite the window.open() to window.open = true

Tags: javascript, window.open

I have a javascript function which actually use the window.open() method to load a page in an Iframe. But I'm sure that by some another script the window.open is overwrited. Thats why I'm getting an error that

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.open is not a function
```

Is there any way to find out that which script actually doing this without finding in all script. Because the page have many scripts.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at an early point in the page load process and set up `window.open` as a Watch item. Then step through the code until it changes.

Comment: Can you post your JavaScript function to check.

Comment: function w(a, b, c, d) {
        a = window.open(a, B, "width=330,height=440");
        return a
    }

Comment: Thanks a lot scott Marcus. Please tell me how to know which is the early point in the page load. Coz I don't know which script is loading or executing first.

Comment: Place a new `script` element at the top of the `head` section of the page with a "dummy" line of code in it, like `console.log("test")`. Then, set a breakpoint on that line and step from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `window.open` to be non-configurable and non-writeable by executing

```
Object.defineProperty( window, "open",
  {  writable: false,
     configurable: false
  }
);
```

before loading or executing other scripts.

Chrome then reports an attempt to set `window.open` to `true` as

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'open' of object '#<Window>'`

along with details of where the attempt was made. Firefox behaves similarly with an error message of

> `TypeError: "open" is read-only`

---

Note that [MDN description of modifying existing properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), at June 1 2018 states that attempting to write to a non-writeable property "doesn't throw an error either". This appears to be incorrect and does not match the code example comment.